# Why does the eventCount change when adding or removing metrics in the page-view event in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to know how many page-views have occurred for every page on our client's website. I was wondering if there is someone who could explain why these two requests might change the results in GA4. The first request I send to Google Analytics is

```
request is property: "properties/MyPropertyId"
dimensions {
  name: "date"
}
dimensions {
  name: "eventName"
}
dimensions {
  name: "customEvent:page_location"
}
metrics {
  name: "eventCount"
}
metrics {
  name: "eventsPerSession"
}
metrics {
  name: "eventValue"
}
date_ranges {
  start_date: "2023-10-17"
  end_date: "2023-10-17"
}
dimension_filter {
  filter {
    field_name: "eventName"
    string_filter {
      match_type: EXACT
      value: "page_view"
    }
  }
}
```

which I am requesting the `metrics`

- eventCount
- eventsPerSession
- eventValue

This request returns almost twice as much information compared to the following request that includes only one metric, which is `eventCount`
The second request is:

```
 request is property: "properties/MyPropertyId"
dimensions {
  name: "date"
}
dimensions {
  name: "eventName"
}
dimensions {
  name: "customEvent:page_location"
}
metrics {
  name: "eventCount"
}
date_ranges {
  start_date: "2023-10-17"
  end_date: "2023-10-17"
}
dimension_filter {
  filter {
    field_name: "eventName"
    string_filter {
      match_type: EXACT
      value: "page_view"
    }
  }
}
limit: 100000
```

Why might the **Metrics** change the number of records returned (for page-views)? I assumed these two metrics would merely add statistics. Why might some page_locations and their associated eventCounts disappear?